# Spring Data JPA select Distinct values with ability to use Pageable

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I use Spring Data JPA in project. I have next Entity Bean "TABLE". I have created own repository

```
TableRepository extends JpaRepository<Table, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<TABLE>.
```

Also I've created Specification to select filtered data. I have bean with items that should be selected and group them in one list of *.in()* predicates (something like "*SELECT * FROM WHERE ID in(...) AND VALUE in(...) AND VALUE2 in(...) ...*")

```
public static Specification<Table> filteredListOfValues(final FilterRequestsParametersBean filterRequestsParametersBean) {
        return new Specification<Table>() {

            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Table> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
                List<Predicate> listOfPredicates = createListOfPredicates(root, filterRequestsParametersBean);
                return criteriaBuilder.and(listOfPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[listOfPredicates.size()]));
            }
        };
    }
```

After that I *findAll()* items with *TableRepository* and *Pageable* parameter.

```
this.getTableRepository().findAll(where(filteredListOfValues(filterRequestsParametersBean)), pageable);
```

*Table* view:

```
id, value, etc..
 1,   1,   ...
 2,   1,   ...
 3,   2,   ...
 4,   2,   ...
 5,   3,   ...
 6,   5,   ...
```

And question. How can I select all values that are distinct from field *VALUE* in *TABLE* with using Pageable.

---

Of course I can use HashMap, but I will not have facilities of Pageable from Spring Data JPA. I need sorting and paging.

I also can use Specification for one field Value, like:

```
    public static Specification<Long> filteredListOfValues(final FilterRequestsParametersBean filterRequestsParametersBean) {
            return new Specification<Long>() {

                public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Long> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {

....//somethind like that
criteriaQuery.select(root.<Long> get("value")).distinct(true);
....
List<Predicate> listOfPredicates = createListOfPredicates(root, filterRequestsParametersBean);
                    return criteriaBuilder.and(listOfPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[listOfPredicates.size()]));
                }
            };
        }
```

but in that case, method findAll() from repository TableRepository only can accept specification like: `JpaSpecificationExecutor<Table>`, not `JpaSpecificationExecutor<Long>`

Thanks.